# How to store data in database onclick button?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am working on an exam portal with Laravel I have a table "question" with questions list.
I have a view page "test.blade.php" where displayed one by one question to the student when student click "saves and next" button. but I have no idea how to store data in the table. I want store question id and answer in the database. when the student clicks on "Submit Test" Button.

**test.blade.php**

```
    @foreach ($newtest as $key => $value)
  <div class="questions">
      <h2>{!! $value->question !!}</h2>
      <form class="options" id="form_id">
          <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value="{!!$value->option1!!}">{!!$value->option1!!}
          <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value="{!!$value->option2!!}">{!!$value->option2 !!}
          <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value="{!!$value->option3!!}">{!!$value->option3!!}
          <input class="option" type="radio" name="question2" value="{!!$value->option4!!}">{!!$value->option4!!}
      </form>
  </div>
@endforeach
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id='next' value="Next" onlick="sum_values()">
  <hr>
```

**Script Code**

```
   var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();
   var currentQuestion = 0;
   $questions = $('.questions');
   $questions.hide();
   $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();

   $('#next').click(function () {

  $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {
  currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;

  if (currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
   var result = sum_values()
    alert(result);
   } else {
    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();

 }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first in your view file add form tag and in add your questions in form tag.then add form method post. then in controller get form data using Request $request. then pass this $request in create method to add data into the table.

Comment: I want to hold all answers with the question is when student click on submit test button then store all data.

Comment: actually i cant understand what excetly you want.

Comment: I want to hold all answer with question id in an array until the student click on "submit test" Button.